# How can you reuse ImagePyramids in SimpleElastix?

Tags: python, elastix-itk

I am using [SimpleElastix](https://github.com/SuperElastix/SimpleElastix/) to perform image registration. I am trying to align different images (aka *moving image*s) to the same template (*fixed image*). One of the slowest parts is `Preparation of the image pyramids`. How can I speed it up ?

I was thinking it would save some time if I could only compute the pyramids once for the *fixed* image and reuse them afterwards, but I can't figure out how to do so.